# Installation of Cucumber in Rails 3 without helper files

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, cucumber

I'm quite new to ruby and ruby on rails and I'm trying to add Cucumber to my new rails 3 application.

My Gemfile contains this section:

```
group :test, :development do
  gem 'rspec-rails', '~>2.5'
end

group :test do
  # Pretty printed test output
  gem 'cucumber-rails'
  gem 'capybara'
  gem 'database_cleaner'
end
```

To install Cucumber first I've run:

```
bundle install --binstubs
```

and after all my gems are installed I've run:

```
rails generate cucumber:install --rspec --capybara
```

My problem is that during installation of cucumber those changes are made:

```
create  config/cucumber.yml
create  script/cucumber
chmod  script/cucumber
create  features/step_definitions
create  features/support
create  features/support/env.rb
exist  lib/tasks
create  lib/tasks/cucumber.rake
gsub  config/database.yml
gsub  config/database.yml
force  config/database.yml
```

but as I understand more files should be created (some helpers file) - like this:

```
create  config/cucumber.yml
create  script/cucumber
chmod  script/cucumber
create  features/step_definitions
create  features/step_definitions/web_steps.rb
create  features/support
create  features/support/paths.rb
create  features/support/selectors.rb
create  features/support/env.rb
exist  lib/tasks
create  lib/tasks/cucumber.rake
gsub  config/database.yml
gsub  config/database.yml
force  config/database.yml
```

Could somebody tell me what am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After some searching in the internet I'm able to answer to this question by myself ;)

It turned out that everything is ok with this Cucumber installation. Currently there is a change in 'cucumber-rails' gem and web_steps.rb (and others) file isn't generated anymore. About the reason you can read here: ['The training wheels came off'](http://aslakhellesoy.com/post/11055981222/the-training-wheels-came-off)

The problem has occurred because I learn Ruby on Rails from ["Rails 3 in Action" book](http://www.manning.com/katz/) in which old behavior of 'cucumber-rails' gem is described.